# Implement Byte serving for Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to implement video Player in Angular using Spring Boot Rest API. I can play the video but I can't make video seeking. Every time the video starts over and over again when I use Chrome or Edge.

I tried this endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/play_video/{video_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPreview1(@PathVariable("video_id") String video_id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = null;
        try {
            String file = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
            Path path = Paths.get(file);
            byte[] image = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.setContentLength(image.length);
            result = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I found this post which gives some ides: [How to Implement HTTP byte-range requests in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427339/how-to-implement-http-byte-range-requests-in-spring-mvc)

But currently it's not working. Video is again playing from the start when I try to shift the position.

I use this player: https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-plyr

I have configured it this way:

```
<div class="media">
        <div
          class="class-video mr-3 mb-1"
          plyr
          [plyrPlaysInline]="true"
          [plyrSources]="gymClass.video"
          (plyrInit)="player = $event"
          (plyrPlay)="played($event)">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          {{ gymClass.description }}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What does the angular code look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### First solution: Using `FileSystemResource`

FileSystemResource internally handles byte-range header support, reading and writing the appropriate headers.

Two problems with this approach.

1. It uses `FileInputStream` internally for reading files. This is fine for small files, but not for large files served through byte-range requests. `FileInputStream` will read the file from the beginning and discard the not needed content until it reches the requested start offset. This can cause slowdowns with larger files.
2. It sets `"application/json"` as the `"Content-Type"` response header. So, I provide my own `"Content-Type"` header. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213297/13236005)

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Stream3 {
    @GetMapping(value = "/play_video/{video_id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> stream(@PathVariable("video_id") String video_id) {
        String filePathString = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";        
        final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(filePathString), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

### Second solution: Using `HttpServletResponse` and `RandomAccessFile`

With `RandomAccessFile` you can implement support for byte-range requests. The advantage over `FileInputStream`, is that you don't need to read the file from the beginning every time there is a new range request, making this method usable also for larger files. `RandomAccessFile` has a method called `seek(long)` which calls the C method `fseek()`, which directly moves the pointer for the file to the requested offset.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Stream {
    @GetMapping(value = "/play_video/{video_id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void stream(        
            @PathVariable("video_id") String video_id,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Range", required = false) String rangeHeader,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            long rangeStart = 0;
            long rangeEnd;
            String filePathString = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
            Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);
            Long fileSize = Files.size(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePathString, "r");
            try (file) {
                if (rangeHeader == null) {
                    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Length", fileSize.toString());
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                    long pos = rangeStart;
                    file.seek(pos);
                    while (pos < fileSize - 1) {                        
                        file.read(buffer);
                        os.write(buffer);
                        pos += buffer.length;
                    }
                    os.flush();
                    return;
                }

                String[] ranges = rangeHeader.split("-");
                rangeStart = Long.parseLong(ranges[0].substring(6));
                if (ranges.length > 1) {
                    rangeEnd = Long.parseLong(ranges[1]);
                } else {
                    rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
                }
                if (fileSize < rangeEnd) {
                    rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
                }

                String contentLength = String.valueOf((rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 1);
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);
                response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes" + " " + rangeStart + "-" + rangeEnd + "/" + fileSize);
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT.value());
                long pos = rangeStart;
                file.seek(pos);
                while (pos < rangeEnd) {                    
                    file.read(buffer);
                    os.write(buffer);
                    pos += buffer.length;
                }
                os.flush();

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        }

    }

}
```

### Third solution: Also using `RandomAccessFile`, but `StreamingResponseBody` instead of `HttpServletResponse`

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Stream2 {
    @GetMapping(value = "/play_video/{video_id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> stream(
            @PathVariable("video_id") String video_id,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Range", required = false) String rangeHeader) {        
        try {
            StreamingResponseBody responseStream;
            String filePathString = "/opt/videos/" + video_id + ".mp4";
            Path filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);
            Long fileSize = Files.size(filePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];      
            final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

            if (rangeHeader == null) {
                responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                responseHeaders.add("Content-Length", fileSize.toString());
                responseStream = os -> {
                    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePathString, "r");
                    try (file) {
                        long pos = 0;
                        file.seek(pos);
                        while (pos < fileSize - 1) {                            
                            file.read(buffer);
                            os.write(buffer);
                            pos += buffer.length;
                        }
                        os.flush();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                };
                return new ResponseEntity<>(responseStream, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            String[] ranges = rangeHeader.split("-");
            Long rangeStart = Long.parseLong(ranges[0].substring(6));
            Long rangeEnd;
            if (ranges.length > 1) {
                rangeEnd = Long.parseLong(ranges[1]);
            } else {
                rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
            }
            if (fileSize < rangeEnd) {
                rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
            }

            String contentLength = String.valueOf((rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 1);
            responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
            responseHeaders.add("Content-Length", contentLength);
            responseHeaders.add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            responseHeaders.add("Content-Range", "bytes" + " " + rangeStart + "-" + rangeEnd + "/" + fileSize);
            final Long _rangeEnd = rangeEnd;
            responseStream = os -> {
                RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePathString, "r");
                try (file) {
                    long pos = rangeStart;
                    file.seek(pos);
                    while (pos < _rangeEnd) {                        
                        file.read(buffer);
                        os.write(buffer);
                        pos += buffer.length;
                    }
                    os.flush();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            };
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseStream, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

In your component.ts:

You can change the currently displaying video with playVideoFile()

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  videoSources: Plyr.Source[];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const fileName = 'sample';
    this.playVideoFile(fileName);
  }

  playVideoFile(fileName: string) {
    this.videoSources = [
      {
        src: `http://localhost:8080/play_video/${fileName}`,
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

And the html:

```
<div
  #plyr
  plyr
  [plyrPlaysInline]="false"
  [plyrSources]="videoSources"
></div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I checked, all three java controllers are working, I can also skip in the video.

Comment: Which one of the solutions will consume less resources if we have hundreds of clients?

Comment: 2. or 3. You can also check out spring reactive. Spring reactive lets you handle function execution in an asynchronous way. That approach works well with `AsynchronousFileChannel`, which is using the native function  `readFile(long handle, long address, int len, long offset, long overlapped)`. The offset here is the position in the file being read. This is not the case with `FileInputStream`, which is using `readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len)` where the offset is the position in the destination buffer.

Comment: In azure-core there is already an implementation of bridging reactor(the reactive library that spring reactive uses) and `AsynchronousFileChannel` together. So if you want to do it that way, you can find documentation here https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-core/1.1.0/com/azure/core/util/FluxUtil.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `<video />` element in Chrome, seeking only works if the endpoint implements partial content requests by honouring requests with a [Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) and respond with a [206 Partial Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206) response.

Comment: I use this player: https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-plyr