# How to export huge records(50k) from database in csv file in springboot

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 50k records in my oracle db and I need to export all the data to the csv file. It is using a native query in respository file.

Here is the controller file.

```
@PostMapping( value=Constants.DOWNLOAD)
@ApiOperation("download file for approvals")
public ResponseEntity<String> downloadFile(
    @RequestBody @ApiParam(value = "Payload Body", required = true ) 
ApiDownload apiDownload) throws Exception {
try {
    return mergeDebtService.downloadFile(apiDownload);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new InvalidInputException(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Here is the service file.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> downloadFile(ApiDownload apiDownload) throws Exception {
List<Integer> listIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Object[]> listObj = new ArrayList<>();
boolean blnAll=false;

if(UserMap.getRole()!=null && UserMap.getRole().equals("ADMIN")) {
        listObj = ddmApprovalsRepository.findAllData(ddmUserMap.getProfileType());
    }else {
        listObj =ddmApprovalsRepository.findData(apiDownload.getLoginName());
    }
}


File directory = new File("/tmp/uploads");
directory.mkdir();
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/tmp/uploads"));

    try {
                
    if(directory.exists()) {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(directory);
        directory.mkdir();
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/tmp/uploads"));
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        
        // if the file is being accessed then it can throw error. 
    }

FILE_EXISTS=true;
ExcelFileGenerator fileGenerator = new ExcelFileGenerator();
String fileName =fileGenerator.generateCSVFile(listObj, 
apiApprovalsDownload.getLoginName(),"/tmp/uploads",cbControlParams,blnAll);
    
File file = new File("/tmp/uploads/"+fileName);
return ResponseEntity.status(200).header("filename", fileName).body("downloaded 
successfully");
}
```

It is taking almost 2 min to respond through the Api, how can I reduce the response timing. As it is giving 504 gateway timeout error .

Comment: 504 indicates that a subsequent call is timing out, which I would assume is your findAllData or findData method. If you post that code someone could help you.

Comment: @Magnus fillAllData and findData contains a native query at repository file. I cant change that. If anything can be done at service file and controller file..Please do suggest

Answer (score 0):

First step is to step away from list based processing.
Currently you create a pretty big list of entities before even starting to create the file.
Instead use a `Stream` as the result type, so writing out the data can interleave with reading the data.

The next step is to get rid of JPA and entities.
Instead use a SQL statement that returns the data as close to the target format as you can manage.
Run that query using a [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and a [`RowCallbackHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html)

If it is still not returning fast enough you should skip the step of writing the file to disc before returning it and instead start streaming it to the client directly. [Downloading large files via Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694168/downloading-large-files-via-spring-mvc) should help with that.